# Angular parent and child controller communication

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to access/modify some variable in the parent controller from the child controller.  This variable is a promise (some $http request) so at the time I render the elements in the child controller this variable still doesn't exist.

I realized using ng-if can help me solve this problem.  But the 2 scopes cannot communicate.  My questions is:

1. how do I two-way bind the variables in 2 scope?  Is this the correct way to do it? ..
2. is there ways that I don't need to use this ng-if? I have like 2-3 promise variables waiting there and I don't want multiple ng-if statements in an element. Is this possible?

http://jsbin.com/rahidukuvi/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to create a service (which uses the singleton pattern) that can be shared between the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use $scope.$watch in the child controller to wait for any variable value change upon ajax callback in parent controller. Inside $scope.$watch callback in the child controller you may change the variable value as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

You would use broadcast to let child controllers know of value changed. You would then listen to that in the child controller and do necessary. See sample code below

```
    .controller('MyController',
    function($scope, $interpolate, $timeout) {

        //$scope.sssss = {};

        $scope.$watch('sssss.a', function() {
            $scope.$broadcast('valueChanged', $scope.sssss)
        });

        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.sssss = {
                a: '12345'
            };
        }, 2000);



    })
.controller('MyChildController',
    function($scope, $interpolate, $timeout) {
        $scope.$on('valueChanged', function(event, value) {
            $scope.ttttt = value.a + '123';
        });


    });
```

Comment: is the only way using $watch?  The reason why I am doing tis is I am passing multiple promises into the child controller and if I have multiple $watch this would be really complicated....

Comment: But would you not create watch just on the parent controller and then broadcast about the change to all child controllers that care about it? Unless I have misunderstood